# adding texture to shape in WPF and Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

How can I add a texture to a let's say rectangle such when I stretch the object on canvas it would cover up while being resized?

Thank you

not that I care about negative points but those who leave this kind of scoring at least could be a little beneficial by pointing to a solution since they feel this is a low level question so I'm assuming they know the answer. I have searched on blend 4 and related topics to xaml but did not find a direction.

Comment: what do you mean by "cover up" ? Could you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess from "cover up" meant maintaining the texture as shape or object grows. Let's say we have a rectangle with a texture and dropped on canvas. Now, as you change the size (width and height) the texture will grow as well.

Comment: I think designing a mesh in photoshop and importing it into Blend 4 and assigning it to a my shape would be one solution.

Comment: I think that will work - as for the negative points, I think you got it because of an "unclear" question, not an simple one.

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as an imagebrush for the fill of the rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Width="auto" Height="auto" Name="myRectangle">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\sample.gif"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

**SOURCE:** http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/4c70e94b-23a1-4533-9332-eaa08bcf113d

**OUTPUT:**

image credit: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/bringing-self-driving-cars-to-nascar.html

[image]